# How do I get the day portion(as a string/char) from a date and run tests on it in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can someone just tell me why this doesn't work. As far as I know, I've put the string into the variable and wanted to test it but it didn't seem to work and brought up errors.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    DATETODAY DATE := SYSDATE;
    DAYT VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
   SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY') INTO DAYT FROM DUAL;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The date today is '||DATETODAY ||' and it is ' ||DAYT);

   IF DAYT = 'SATURDAY' OR DAYT = 'SUNDAY' THEN
       : DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its is a weekend');
   ELSE
       : DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its a week day');
   END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Get rid of the colons before the DBMS_OUTPUT

Comment: Thanks man Im new to PLSQL and I thought it was the normal syntax. phew, gone nuts over it so decided to ask.

Comment: One thing to be aware of though concatenating a date (`DATETODAY`) with a string in `.put_line` will lead to implicit conversion to default `nls_date_format` It's better to convert it to a string of desired format and then concatenate

Comment: The outputs would be interesting. But you should be on the safe side with DayOfWeek (see my answer).

Comment: And what do those `:` do in front of the `dmbs_output.put_lines()`. I think you should remove them..

Comment: Is there some computer language that uses colons like that? Never seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'day') DayName,
       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'd')   DayOfWeek,
       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd')  DayOfMonth,
       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'ddd') DayOfYear
  FROM DUAL;
```

`DayName` is bound to the language of your db. Better use DayOfWeek.
Anyway you should run the example-sql provided to compare your output. Perhaps a `UPPER()` could also help you.

Comment: `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'D' )` also depends on your `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter as some locales start their first day of the week on a different day (America = Sunday and France = Monday, for example).

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE( date_value, 'DAY' )` returns a fixed-length string (not a variable-length); this means that it is right-padded with space characters:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/324)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2018-05-05', 'DAY' ) AS day,
       DUMP( TO_CHAR( DATE '2018-05-05', 'DAY' ) ) As dump
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/324/0)**:

```
|       DAY |                                    DUMP |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------|
| SATURDAY  | Typ=1 Len=9: 83,65,84,85,82,68,65,89,32 |
```

Shows that the final character has ASCII code 32 - a space.

So your code should be:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  DATETODAY DATE := SYSDATE;
  DAYT VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   DAYT := TO_CHAR( DATETODAY ,'DAY');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The date today is '||DATETODAY ||' and it is ' ||DAYT);

   IF DAYT = 'SATURDAY ' OR DAYT = 'SUNDAY   ' THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its is a weekend');
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its a week day');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Which (for my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting of `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`) outputs:

```
The date today is 2018-05-04 14:32:25 and it is FRIDAY   
Today is FRIDAY    and its a week day
```

Changing the initial assignment to `DATETODAY DATE := DATE '2018-05-05';` then the output is:

```
The date today is 2018-05-05 00:00:00 and it is SATURDAY 
Today is SATURDAY  and its is a weekend
```

However, you could also write it as:

```
DECLARE
  DATETODAY DATE := SYSDATE;
  DAYT VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   DAYT := TO_CHAR( DATETODAY ,'DAY');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The date today is '||DATETODAY ||' and it is ' ||DAYT);

   IF DATETODAY - TRUNC( DATETODAY, 'IW' ) >= 5 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its is a weekend');
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today is '||DAYT||' and its a week day');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

As `TRUNC( DATETODAY, 'IW' )` will truncate the date back to the start of the ISO week (always midnight on Monday) and this is independent of any `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` or `NLS_TERRITORY` settings that affect the `TO_CHAR` function.